# Can Brook have another Devil Fruit?

Tags: one-piece

As per One Piece logic, a person cannot have 2 Devil Fruit powers. 
The Yomi Yomi no Mi fruit revives the one who eats it. The powers of this fruit are a one-time use, and has been used up after Brook was revived. Can Brook now have another Devil Fruit?

Comment: Do you want to know what people think or if there has been any evidence given to support that he can have another? Because those are two different questions, one of which isn't allowed and one of which is.

Comment: I don't really follow the manga. So i want to know if there has been any clues to what my question is!

Comment: I don't believe anything about this is mentioned in the manga as of yet. As black beard's way of acquiring another devil fruit is also still unknown all answers given would be speculation only

Comment: This question is fine, just needed to be reworded. Quite frankly, I expected the experienced users to help the newbie, rather than nitpick.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yomi Yomi no Mi's ability to revive its eater is just the tip of the iceberg. Brook *thought* it was the only purpose before the timeskip. However, after the timeskip, he reveals that he has now learnt the *true power* of his Devil Fruit.

The soul of a human who dies normally goes to the land of the dead, but his Devil's Fruit emits a powerful energy that allows his soul to remain in the living world. During the 2 years of training, he has also mastered its other abilities, such as:

- Letting his soul leave and enter his body/skeleton at will
- "Pouring his soul" into his music to show illusions to people
- Summoning cold flames from the underworld
- Surviving damage that would otherwise be fatal (he cannot be seriously injured unless his bones are hurt)

Long story short, Yomi Yomi no Mi is not a "one time use". Brook cannot have another Devil Fruit, unless Oda-sensei's hyper-creative imagination provides him a loophole.