# What will happen if one person eats two Devil Fruits?

Tags: one-piece

If a person has already eaten one Devil Fruit, what will happen to him if he eats another Devil Fruit?

Comment: This might answer your question: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/is-blackbeard-able-to-absorb-more-than-one-devil-fruit/9962#9962

Comment: @EroSɘnnin That is not a duplicate, neither would [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5261/6166) be. Those two questions ask for Blackbeard and Brook specifically. This questions asks in general and would thus result in a completely different answer, because as we know Blackbeard could *consume* 2 fruits, while most other users could not.

Comment: @PeterRaeves I know that this question isn't a duplicate ( I didn't vote to close it btw). I was suggesting  that [this answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/can-blackbeard-consume-more-than-one-devil-fruit/9962#9962) contains details regarding this question

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Ow, right, I see. It seems I didn't properly read your comment and assumed it was one of those auto-generated duplicate comments. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PeterRaeves lol its okay. I should have made the comment clearer :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Their body would explode without a trace, and they would die...**

[image: enter image description here!]

During the Enies Lobby arc, in chapter 385, we see how Jabra gets scared when seeing the [Giraffe Fruit](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Ushi_Ushi_no_Mi,_Model:_Giraffe) and the [Bubble Fruit](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Awa_Awa_no_Mi). He claims that a rumor exists that says that when an *ability* user comes close to a [Devil Fruit](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit), the Devil will come out of the fruit and start fighting with the Devil residing within his body and that would make his body explode. This was immediately countered by Bluenote saying that **Grandline scientists have already uncovered that the body would only explode if two fruits are eaten by the same user**. Therefore it is believed and apparently proven that eating two Devil Fruits would make a person's body explode.

[image: enter image description here!]

Later during the Marineford arc, in chapter 577, we have seen an exception to this case. **Blackbeard was seen to have two Devil Fruits at the same time**. When Whitebeard died, he supposedly extracted the Devil from Whitebeard's body and put it into his own. How Blackbeard was able to extract it and whether his body did not explode due to it being *different*, due to the Dark Fruit powers or due to a different reason, can be read [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/9953/6166).